# Trouble finding elements by xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

Having some trouble selecting the input on a form on the instagram page using find_elements_by_xpath.

The source HTML code looks like this:
[HTML Code from Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OHLn.png)

And this is the code that I'm using, but getting no results when printing the result in console.

```
inputs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//form/div[2]/div/div/input')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get information how to use locators here: [official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver).

You can also need to learn about [Explicit and Implicit Waits](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Input has `name` attribute with value `username`, xpath:

```
inputs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
```

Find elements by name:

```
inputs = browser.find_elements_by_name("username")
```